# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium', yet selenium is listed,

Tags: python, list, pip

I get the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
but when i type pip list i get:

```
Package          Version
---------------- --------
async-generator  1.10
attrs            23.1.0
beautifulsoup4   4.12.2
certifi          2023.5.7
cffi             1.15.1
exceptiongroup   1.1.1
h11              0.14.0
idna             3.4
outcome          1.2.0
pip              23.1.2
pycparser        2.21
PySocks          1.7.1
**selenium         4.9.1**
setuptools       65.5.0
sniffio          1.3.0
sortedcontainers 2.4.0
soupsieve        2.4.1
trio             0.22.0
trio-websocket   0.10.2
urllib3          2.0.2
wsproto          1.2.0
```

Now, I installed the beautifulsoup4 before, with not added environment to path. I dont remember know how I've done that(especially that the python, py, pip didnt work), but eventually i downloaded python from the original site (back then i downloaded from microsoft store). How do i fix that?

Comment: You must have two different versions of Python installed on your computer.  The selenium package is installed for one version, but you're using a different version to actually run your script.

Comment: Show us the exact command you're using to run your code.

Comment: Does it also counts if I downloaded the exact version, but from 2 different sources - 3.11 python i use @JohnGordon

Comment: @JohnGordon I just run python file in visual studio code this is what i get from terminal while running the code: C:/Users/Marcin/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe c:/Users/Marcin/Desktop/pogoda/pogoda.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Marcin\Desktop\pogoda\pogoda.py", line 3, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

Comment: Now show the output from this command `pip --version`

Comment: pip 23.1.2 from C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.11) @JohnGordon

Comment: It looks like you have two separate versions of Python3.11 installed.  One is in `C:/Users/Marcin/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps`, and the other is in `C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311`.

Comment: i can also list the output from cmd, using  where /r c: *selenium* (and bs4 as well, the bs4 works, the selenium doesnt)

Comment: Why did you install python3 twice?

Comment: because, the version i installed firstly was from microsoft store and it didn't have the /scripts file, which is necessery to adding to path, so i installed then from python website, and then it added itself

Comment: Well, anyway, that is the problem.  `pip` is using the version of Python from the official python website, but you're using the Microsoft `python3.11.exe` version to actually run your code.

Comment: Yeah, i can confirm, that is because the pip and python command didnt work all the time. So should i delete the version from microsoft?

Comment: Yes, if you don't need the Microsoft version for any other reason.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have two Python versions installed at your system at the same time. That's possible in your case as you have installed it once from the Microsoft Store and then from the Python website.

To get things definitely clean, in your case I would uninstall both versions (they should both show up in the Installed Apps section of your Settings app) and then keep only the one downloaded through the Python website.

As an additional note, I wouldn't recommend installing packages directly on your Python default environment, but create a **virtual environment** for your project instead. That will allow to keep your default environment clean and have each project with its own dependencies (which may need different versions for a same package, depending on each project).

This is extremely easy to do in Windows: https://medium.com/co-learning-lounge/create-virtual-environment-python-windows-2021-d947c3a3ca78